# HTML Email formatting messed up

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Hello guys i am trying to send an email with HTML in it, and of course i know that the formatting and alot of CSS is not supported in Outlook, but i was wondering why this simple thing was showing broken, is there any quick fix or a workaround/alternative? look at how the buttons should appear:

http://puu.sh/84ijt.png

But they appear like this:

http://puu.sh/84ijA.png

Here is the code for it:

```
<tr>
    <td style="display:block;min-height:38px;max-height:38px;">
        <p style="margin-left:15px;">
            <a style="font-size: 10pt;color: #fff;text-align: center;display:block; width:70px;height:25px;text-decoration:none;background-color: #c64141;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;border: 1px solid #901313;margin-right:10px;float:left;" 
href="link here..">Enquire</a>
            <a href="link here.." style="font-size: 10pt;color: #fff;text-align: center;display:block; width:70px;height:25px;text-decoration:none;background-color: #c64141;padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;border: 1px solid #901313;float:left;">Full Details</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    </tr>
</td>
```

Comment: Unless it's changed I think that outlook uses word as the engine to view html emails (which i think is weird) So it's quite likely thats another annoying simple thing that doesnt work. KM123 solution for an image instead is a good option.

Comment: At least your `tr` and `td` end tags are the wrong way around, and the `div` end tag appears from nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an email marketer I suggest you use an image for your button. Especially if it is a call to action. The one thing you don't want to be broken is that, and the only way you can trust it wont be and that is to use an image within a table cell.

I hope that helps!

Comment: background images are not supported in Outlook.

Comment: Never use background images. You should literally make the whole button an image and then use <img src="myimage.jpg"> and then wrap it in a link

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of mis-information in this thread.

You can use an image for a button, however more advanced designers are trending towards "bulletproof" buttons these days. They display with images turned off. See this link: [buttons.cm](http://buttons.cm/)

Background images are supported in Outlook, but only in the `<body>` tag OR using VML, see the buttons.cm link above or [backgrounds.cm](http://backgrounds.cm/) for examples.

Back to your specific example, there are a few ways to accomplish it, but here is how I would do it:

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border:solid 1px #000000;">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:10px;">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="50">&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td width="90" height="30" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#c64141" style="border:solid 1px #000000; font-size:12px;">
            <a href="" style="color: #FFFFFE; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Enquire</a>
          </td>
          <td width="20">&nbsp;
          </td>
          <td width="90" height="30" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#c64141" style="border:solid 1px #000000; font-size:12px;">
            <a href="" style="color: #FFFFFE; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;">Full Details</a>
          </td>
          <td width="50">&nbsp;
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

On a side note, you need to use the 6-digit hex colors in html email, and don't waste your time with the following css properties as they have inconsistent support:

- `margin` (use `padding` instead)
- `text-align` (use `align=""` instead)
- `min-height` & `max-height`
- `float` (use align="" instead)
- `background-color` (use `bgcolor=""` instead)

Also, avoid shorthand like `padding:5px 5px 0px 5px;`. Unfortunately you need to write it out `padding:5px; padding-bottom:0;`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the `<td>` the background-color? (or another container)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
<a href="#">
<span style="display:block;background-color:red;color:white;width:100px;text-align:center;">link</span>
</a>
```

I haven't tested in Outlook but it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Using images isn't the best solution, especially since most of the time emails are rendered without images until the user accepts to view images.

The way I do it is a table with in a table, so something like this:

`<table width="outside container width here">
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <table style="apply your styles here, background colors, paddings etc (do not use margins, poorly supported.)" height="height of inner container" width="inner container width here" align="however you want it aligned">
         <tbody><tr><td><a href="#link">Your button actually goes here</a></td></tr></tbody>
       </table>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>`